# How to remove module from "target list" in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

In GHCI, you can add modules from your current project using `:add module`, or you can add modules to the current scope using `:module + module`.  The modules loaded using `:add` will be automatically reloaded when you use the `:reload` command, but must be source modules, and cannot come from an external package.

If you accidentally use `:add` rather than `:module +` to attempt to load a module, future reloads always fail with an error message that the module is a package module rather than a source module. How can you remove the module so that reload can be used successfully again, without resetting the entire list of source modules via `:load`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `:load` (or `:cd`) are the only ways to get rid of the target list. The only other function that changes the target list is `:add`, and as you know that one only adds additional targets.

However, [judging by the source](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/c37a583fb9059053f83f1ab0c3cb7eb7047b1a31/ghc/GHCi/UI.hs), a fix shouldn't be that hard. If you're willing to recompile GHC, something like this should work:

```
ghciCommands :: [Command]
ghciCommands = map mkCmd [
  ...
  ("rem",       keepGoingPaths removeModule,   completeFilename),
  ...

-- | @:rem@ command
removeModule :: [FilePath] -> InputT GHCi ()
removeModule files = do
  lift revertCAFs
  files'  <- mapM expandPath files
  targets <- mapM (\m -> GHC.guessTarget m Nothing) files'
  mapM_ GHC.removeTarget targets
  _ <- doLoadAndCollectInfo False LoadAllTargets
  return ()
```

That being said, I haven't tried that yet. Also, this might be worth a [ticket on the official tracker](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/report).

Comment: Thanks.  Reading the documentation I was thinking this might be the case, but wasn't sure there wasn't something I was missing.

Comment: @Jules: You're welcome. If you open a ticket on trac, either [edit] or leave a comment, so that I can get this answer up to date (or add a new answer). Otherwise, if you don't open a ticket, I'll have a look whether I can finally create an account and file the ticket and patch myself (either this or next week).